# MySql issue in linux. Failed to start mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not found

Tags: mysql, linux, database, mariadb

when I do:

```
sudo service MySQL start
```

it gives me this error:

```
Failed to start mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not found.
```

and when I type this command :

```
MySQL -v
```

this error happens:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

but this directory **/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock** doesnt exist
i tried to remove it but i cant because the last issue.

Comment: always check the mysql error log to check for errors

Comment: where do i find the log ?

Comment: that depends on the linux version